# use row value as column and columns as rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a query in which I use pivot to transform row values into columns. That I am able to do fine. But the requirement is to also use the other columns as row values.

The table and query I have tried can be checked [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/572a5a/7). 
The required output is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/baf77/1).

From the query, I need the values of 'C' to be columns then the other columns (A, B, D & E) to be row values for the first column.

Is it possible to use one single pivot query to display the required output? If not, what would be the best approach to the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/572a5a/10)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
    A varchar(10),
    B varchar(10),
    C int,
    D varchar(10),
    E varchar(10)
)

GO

INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES('A1', 'B1', 1, 'D1', 'E1');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES('A2', 'B2', 2, 'D2', 'E2');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES('A3', 'B3', 3, 'D3', 'E3');
```

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols =  STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(C) 
                       from Table1
                       group by C
                       order by C
                       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                      ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                      ,1,1,'')

set @query = N';WITH CTE AS
(SELECT *
FROM Table1 UNPIVOT (Vals FOR COLUMNNAMES IN (A,B,D,E))up
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE 
  PIVOT (MAX(Vals)
         FOR C
         IN(' + @cols + N'))p '

exec sp_executesql @query
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/572a5a/10/0)**:

```
| COLUMNNAMES |  1 |  2 |  3 |
|-------------|----|----|----|
|           A | A1 | A2 | A3 |
|           B | B1 | B2 | B3 |
|           D | D1 | D2 | D3 |
|           E | E1 | E2 | E3 |
```